# Mongo/Node: Filtering By Single Properties?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am dealing with a query with a `criteria` object that is being passed as the first argument to this query:

```
module.exports = (criteria, sortProperty, offset = 0, limit = 20) => {
  // write a query that will follow sort, offset, limit options only
  // do not worry about criteria yet
  console.log(criteria);

  const query = Artist.find({ age: { $gte: 19, $lte: 44 } })
    .sort({ [sortProperty]: 1 })
    .skip(offset)
    .limit(limit);

  return Promise.all([query, Artist.count]).then(results => {
    return {
      all: results[0],
      count: results[1],
      offset: offset,
      limit: limit
    };
  });
};
```

By default, the `criteria` object has a single `name` property that is an empty string.

The `age` property points to an object that has both `min` and `max` values assigned to it. I also have a `yearsActive` property inside of the `criteria` object and that also has a `min` and `max` value.

So three different properties: `age`, `name` and `yearsActive`.

This has been an extremely challenging one for me and if you look above that's as far as I got.

When my `criteria` property is console logged it only has a name `{ name: "" }`. It has no `yearsActive` or `age` by default when it first starts. So that is where the point of the sliders come in. When I start moving these sliders around on the frontend, then it gets the `age` and `yearsActive` appended to the `criteria` object.

So I need to figure out how to update the query to consider for example the different ages and I have been considering using an `if` conditional inside a helper function.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @Mani, I expect that when a user drags the `age` or `yearsActive` or inputs a specific `name` and they click the submit button, the UI will update appropriately.

Comment: Is this question related to UI or MongoDB?

Comment: @Mani, maybe I don't understand your question. Are you asking about my expectation of how the application will behave once this implementation is complete? Otherwise, I am unclear as to what "expected result" you mean? I need assistance with the logic that is missing in my code. Perhaps maybe some assistance with a helper function? I am not sure, that's why I posted this question.

Comment: The problem is that it's very **unclear which question you are asking**. A "UI slider" has nothing to do with the "back end" execution of this code. Yes, you can make `criteria` something like `{ name: 'something, minAge: 19, maxAge: 45 }` and then assign that to your query as `{ name: criteria.name, age: { $gte: criteria.minAge, $lte: criteria.maxAge } }` or via some other syntax that references those properties. But how the "UI" assigns those criteria is a completely different question. So you should be clearer about **"which"** question you are actually asking.

Comment: @NeilLunn, I was just sharing the connection between the backend and that UI slider so that everyone can understand whats going on. I guess that was unnecessary. I will give it a shot with what you shared in the comment, but what are your thoughts about throwing that in a helper function, like to build up a filter object? Its not just `age` and `name`, there is also `yearsActive`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I decided to do since the code would look messy to throw all inside the `Artist.find({})` was to create a separate helper function:

```
const buildQuery = (criteria) => {
    console.log(criteria);
};
```

This helper function is being called with the `criteria` object and I have to form up the object in such a way that it will represent the query the way in which I want to search the `Artist` collection.

What made this difficult to wrap my head around was the not very well formed object for searching over a collection with its random properties such as `age` which has a min and a max which Mongo does not know how to deal with by default. MongoDB does not know what min and max mean exactly.

So inside the helper function I made a separate object to `return` from this function thats going to represent the actual `query` that I want to send off to Mongo.

```
const buildQuery = (criteria) => {
    console.log(criteria);
    const query = {};
};
```

I am not modifying the object in anyway, I am just reading some of the desired search results or what the user wants to see from this UI object and so I made this object called `query` and I added the idea of `age`.

```
const buildQuery = (criteria) => {
    console.log(criteria);
    const query = {};
    query.age = {};
};
```

I decided to do an `if` conditional inside of the helper function for the specific age range that I want to find.

```
const buildQuery = (criteria) => {
    console.log(criteria);
    const query = {};
    if (criteria.age) {
        query.age = {};
    }
};
```

So this is where the Mongo query operators come into play. The two operators I want to be concerned with is the greater than or equal to (`$gte`) and the less than or equal to (`$lte`) operators.

This is how I actually implemented in practice:

```
const buildQuery = (criteria) => {
    console.log(criteria);
    const query = {};
    if (criteria.age) {
        query.age = {
            $gte: criteria.age.min,
            $lte: criteria.age.max
        };
    }
};
```

The `query` object here will eventually be returned from the `buildQuery` function:

```
const buildQuery = (criteria) => {
    console.log(criteria);
    const query = {};
    if (criteria.age) {
        query.age = {
            $gte: criteria.age.min,
            $lte: criteria.age.max
        };
    }
    return query;
};
```

That `query` object will be passed off to the find operation:

```
module.exports = (criteria, sortProperty, offset = 0, limit = 20) => {
  // write a query that will follow sort, offset, limit options only
  // do not worry about criteria yet

  const query = Artist.find(buildQuery(criteria))
    .sort({ [sortProperty]: 1 })
    .skip(offset)
    .limit(limit);

  return Promise.all([query, Artist.count]).then(results => {
    return {
      all: results[0],
      count: results[1],
      offset: offset,
      limit: limit
    };
  });
};

const buildQuery = (criteria) => {
    console.log(criteria);
    const query = {};
    if (criteria.age) {
        query.age = {
            $gte: criteria.age.min,
            $lte: criteria.age.max
        };
    }
    return query;
};
```

So what I am doing here is to get the equivalent of `Artist.find({ age: { $gte: minAge, $lte: maxAge })`.

So for `yearsActive` I decided to implement something that is nearly identical:

```
const buildQuery = criteria => {
  console.log(criteria);
  const query = {};
  if (criteria.age) {
    query.age = {
      $gte: criteria.age.min,
      $lte: criteria.age.max
    };
  }

  if (criteria.yearsActive) {

  }

  return query;
};
```

So if the user changes the slider, I am going to expect my criteria object to have a yearsActive property defined on it like so:

```
const buildQuery = criteria => {
  console.log(criteria);
  const query = {};
  if (criteria.age) {
    query.age = {
      $gte: criteria.age.min,
      $lte: criteria.age.max
    };
  }

  if (criteria.yearsActive) {
    query.yearsActive = {
       $gte: criteria.yearsActive.min,
       $lte: criteria.yearsActive.max
     }
  }

  return query;
};
```

Comment: In that case make sense I understand that you're retrieving empty data from age and yearsActive, so I recommended you use an aggregation with the project, also you could mix both the query and use the aggregation to retrieve your data as you want.

Comment: @roag92, could you add that as an answer, because honestly, even though I have gotten as far as I have in the answer I posted above, I still have `yearsActive` to do and I have been unsuccessful integrating that property.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to the comment that I left you.

You have three states at least one when you retrieve the data to the UI. In this case, I would recommend you use aggregation in order to retrieve the data as a model as your business.

For example, the problem as you have is that sometimes you don't know about the max or min value for *age* or *yearsActive*, but also you should have an identifier that could be an **ObjectId** which will be used to update the model identified by that property.

```
Artist.aggregate([
{
    $match: { age: { $gte: 19, $lte: 44 } }
},
{
    $sort: { yourProperty: 1 }
},
{
    $skip: 10
},
{
    $limit: 10
},
{
    $project: {
        // You set your properties to retrieve with the 1 as flag
        propertieX: 1,
        "another.property": 1,
        "age.max": {
            $cond: {
                if: { $eq: [ "", "$age.max" ] },
                then: 0, // Or the value that you want to set it
                else: "$age.max"
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

The other state is when you do the query according to the parameters that you're submitting from the form.

If you assurance to retrieve a model with the logic as you want. For example you should return this model in every request using **$project** and applying the default values when doesn't exist the manipulation in the front-end side as in the searching should be easy to manage.

```
{
    ObjectId: YOUR_OBJECT_ID,
    age: {
        min: YOUR_MIN_VALUE,
        max: YOUR_MAX_VALUE
    },
    yearsActive: {
        min: YOUR_MIN_VALUE,
        max: YOUR_MAX_VALUE
    }
}
```

Finally, when you would send the data to save it you should sent the entire model that you returned but the must important thing is identify only that element by the **ObjectId** to do the update.

**NOTE**: *This is an approach that I will do according with the information that I understand from your question, If I'm bad with me interpretation let me know, and if you want to share more information or open a repository to understand in code, should more easy to me understand the problem*.